# ActionMailer не отправляет письмо на почту

Tags: ruby

Все проходит без ошибок, но на почту ни одно письмо не пришло.
[Логи криейта User](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15630626/)

**environment.rb**

```
    # environment.rb
    # Load the Rails application.
    require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

    # Initialize the Rails application.
    Rails.application.initialize!

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      user_name: 'your_sendgrid_username',
      password: 'your_sendgrid_password',
      domain: 'yourdomain.com',
      address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port: 587,
      authentication: :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

**users_contoller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.token
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :login)
  end
end
```

**user_mailer/welcome_email.thml.slim**

```
doctype html

html
  head
    meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'
  body
    Welcome to example.com,
    = @user.name
    p
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is:
      = @user.login
    p
      To login to the site, just follow this link: = @url
    p
      Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

Comment: Вас должны насторожить: `Unpermitted parameter: password_confirmation`, `DEPRECATION WARNING` и `Sent mail to aaa73731919@gmail.com`. Проблема, по всей видимости, только с последним: письмо ушло, но куда?..

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема заключалась в том, что mailer отправлял меседж от аккаунта которого не существует, создал новый аккаунит и добавил соответствующее  в конфиг, и все прошло с успехом.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно помню (очень смутно помню), то при инициализации, приложение сохраняет свою копию `smtp_settings` и менять их для `ActionMailer::Base` становится просто бессмысленно.
В логах же видно, что произошла попытка отправить письмо и письмо свалилось в консоль (дефолтное поведение для среды `development`)
Правильнее всего было бы указать настройки для конкретной среды в файлах `config/environments/*.rb` т.к. в тестовой среде использование почтовика будет явно лишним. Однако, если, всё-таки, нужно для всех сред прописать параметры, то лучше это сделать в `config/application.eb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
#...
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    #твои настройки
  }
end
```

Кстати, (опять же, если я правильно помню) `config/environments/*.rb` приоритетнее, чем то, что указано в `config/application.eb`. Так что, как минимум для теста, есть возможность вернуть дефолтное поведение.